# How use a random loop with key_generator?

Tags: python, key-generator

```
from key_generator.key_generator import generate 
import random, sys

key= generate(4, '-', 5, 5, type_of_value = 'hex', capital = 'all', seed = 17)
print(key.get_key()
```

Every time I use for in loop give me the same key repeated.

Comment: yes you are right now it's  work just remove seed

Comment: BTW there is a missing parentheses at the end of the last line

Comment: I forgot to put it here

Answer (score 0):

Like Carigenicate already said in the comments, that's because of the seed at the end. The purpose of a seed is to show the same result every time.

So either try removing the seed or generating a random one.

Comment: okay but how to loop it I want to get 10000 key different

Comment: yes you are right now it's  work just remove seed

Comment: Something like this: `for i in range(10000):
    key= generate(4, '-', 5, 5, type_of_value = 'hex', capital = 'all')
    print(key.get_key()
`

Answer (score 0):

try using `random.randint` for generating the seed because in the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/key-generator/) it says that it will generate the same seed for the same input value

```py
key= generate(4, '-', 5, 5, type_of_value = 'hex', capital = 'all', seed = random.randint(0, 1000))
```

(it didn't say if there was a limit for `seed` so I guess you can make the range bigger if you want it more secure)

Comment: it's work but only give me 7 key and repeat them over and over